# Supabase client permission denied for schema public

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql, supabase

Whenever I've try to use @supabase/supabase-js to query the db, I get an error.

```
error: {
    hint: null,
    details: null,
    code: '42501',
    message: 'permission denied for schema public'
}
```

I think it has something to do with Prisma, which I use to handle migrations. The client worked fine when I was just clicking around with a prototype, but after setting up Prisma, it doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I would really like to be able to use the Supabase REST API and Prisma together.

Comment: I am having the same error, using also Prisma and Supabase. Have you been able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 22):

**Cause**: When you exec `prisma migrate reset` or `prisma migrate dev` in the remote Supabase database you may need to reset it. Resetting the database drops the whole database and recreates it. [Source](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate#reset-the-development-database)

This clears all the `GRANT`s that are required for PostgREST to work
You can find the error in the PostgREST documentation at:

https://postgrest.org/en/latest/tutorials/tut0.html?highlight=42501#step-5-run-postgrest

**Solution 1**: Create a brand new project and use only `prisma migrate deploy` on the remote database.

**Solution 2**: Fix the grants manually by granting access to the tables

You can check the difference when you run the following SQL on a brand new Supabase project and your damaged database to observe the differences.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name='members'
```

The following default grants are taken from the supabase github repo at https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/a2fc6d592cb4ea50fd518b99db199a31912040b9/docker/volumes/db/init/00-initial-schema.sql#L26-L29

```
grant usage on schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;

alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema public grant all
    on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema public grant all
    on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema public grant all
    on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
```

Here's a list of default permissions for a sample table `members`

| grantor | grantee | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | privilege_type | is_grantable | with_hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | INSERT | YES | NO |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | SELECT | YES | YES |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | UPDATE | YES | NO |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | DELETE | YES | NO |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | TRUNCATE | YES | NO |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | REFERENCES | YES | NO |
| postgres | postgres | postgres | public | members | TRIGGER | YES | NO |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | INSERT | NO | NO |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | SELECT | NO | YES |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | UPDATE | NO | NO |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | DELETE | NO | NO |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | TRUNCATE | NO | NO |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | REFERENCES | NO | NO |
| postgres | anon | postgres | public | members | TRIGGER | NO | NO |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | INSERT | NO | NO |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | SELECT | NO | YES |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | UPDATE | NO | NO |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | DELETE | NO | NO |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | TRUNCATE | NO | NO |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | REFERENCES | NO | NO |
| postgres | authenticated | postgres | public | members | TRIGGER | NO | NO |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | INSERT | NO | NO |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | SELECT | NO | YES |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | UPDATE | NO | NO |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | DELETE | NO | NO |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | TRUNCATE | NO | NO |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | REFERENCES | NO | NO |
| postgres | service_role | postgres | public | members | TRIGGER | NO | NO |

Comment: The command almost worked for me, see my answer below for the ones that worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Please don't just run a Grant All Privileges to every type of possible user access to your database.

The access needed depends on what the sql is doing.
Ie, If only need to select and insert then only provide those privileges, concerning if giving everyone access to truncate, and delete tables in your schema...

I was having the issue of using supabase.rpc() to run some postgres functions. This function would select some data from a table, update a table, then insert into a new table.

First error I had was

```
{
 code: '42501',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'permission denied for schema public'
}
```

Which was resolved with

```
grant usage on schema "public" to anon;
grant usage on schema "public" to authenticated;
```

That then lead to this error

```
   {
  code: '42501',
 details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'permission denied for table xxx'
 }
```

Which that was resolved with

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "public" TO authenticated;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "public" TO anon;
```

See below for some sources (because thats what 9th grade english class taught me to do)

[Github issue](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/4956)

[Docs about Grants](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-grant-access-to-users.html)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Other answers are making the users to give all privileges to all users (including anon/public key which may be leaked and used by anyone to access your database)

Comment: Thank you! The only answer that properly worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Run this SQL script in Supabase SQL editor.

source: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/integrations/prisma#troubleshooting

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "auth";
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "extensions";
create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp"      with schema extensions;
create extension if not exists pgcrypto         with schema extensions;
create extension if not exists pgjwt            with schema extensions;

grant usage on schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
grant usage on schema extensions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter user supabase_admin SET search_path TO public, extensions; -- don't include the "auth" schema

grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, supabase_admin;
grant all privileges on all functions in schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, supabase_admin;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, supabase_admin;

alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;

alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema public grant all on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema public grant all on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema public grant all on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;

alter role anon set statement_timeout = '3s';
alter role authenticated set statement_timeout = '8s';
```

Comment: +1 - this helped fix my issue when running migrations with alembic (Python) without having to recreate my whole database

Comment: Thanks for adding the source, your snippet will work but the source link allowed us to pick it up right away.

Answer (score 2):

@kachar's answer almost worked for me, below let me share the grants SQL that worked for me today

```
grant usage on schema local to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter user supabase_admin SET search_path TO public, local, extensions; -- add all schemas to search path but don't include the "auth" schema

grant all privileges on all tables in schema local to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, supabase_admin;
grant all privileges on all functions in schema local to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, supabase_admin;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema local to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, supabase_admin;

alter default privileges in schema local grant all on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema local grant all on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema local grant all on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;

alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema local grant all
    on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema local grant all
    on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges for user supabase_admin in schema local grant all
    on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've previously mangled my Supabase project by using the Flyway "clean" functionality ( which deletes all the stuff in a schema so you can run your migrations again).

You can see the discussion of it here: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/344#discussioncomment-182886

It seems the Supabase project schema has a bunch of Supabase-specific configuration in it and if you mess with it - weird things will happen.

You might want to look into if Prisma does any stuff to the schema that you didn't realise it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Because Supabase doesn't give us superuser role in online SQL Editor, you will get the error to run the sql from the previous answers like:

```
ERROR:  42501: "supabase_admin" is a reserved role, only superusers can modify it
```

So you need to use this SQL instead:

```sql
grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
grant all privileges on all functions in schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
grant all privileges on all sequences in schema public to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;

alter default privileges in schema public grant all on tables to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on functions to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;
alter default privileges in schema public grant all on sequences to postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role;

grant usage on schema "public" to anon;
grant usage on schema "public" to authenticated;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and i just create an entire new project on Supabase and then "npx prisma migrate dev" to re generate my tables, and it works like a charm! I dont know when i broke my Supabase project. If you cannot re generate your tables because you have data on it, consider it migrate data to new project because it really works out!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on [supabase stripe](https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments) I create the table's using supabase [table editor](https://supabase.com/dashboard/project/_/editor) for my existing project then I came across this issue

```
{
 code: '42501',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'permission denied for schema public'
}
```

Again I re-created a new supabase project from scratch but this time I went with supabase **[automated way](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/subscription-starter)** which run the SQL migrations to set up the Database schema on my account, which was **working perfectly**

Now to see whats happening in between them, I compared both the tables **manual** vs **auto generated** using [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/)

I found that **GRANT** is missing from my manually generated table.
I just updated my queries not it works for me.

[image: pgAgmin]