# How to access custom schema from supabase-js client?

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I love Supabase but our team needs to use schema functionality that PostgreSQL offers - unfortunately we have been unsuccessfully to make schemas working so far.

**Other info:**

- PostgreSQL 14
- newest version of the Supabase JS SDK's
- we have supabase hosted with Supabase's pro plan

**What we have tried:**

1. We created a new schema and added access to all types of authentication (*why all? We first thought that maybe there is an error with authentication*):

   ```
   CREATE SCHEMA Brano;
   GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA Brano TO postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, dashboard_user;
   ```
2. Exposed schema to the API via this setting:

   [image]
3. Tried the following code:

   ```
   var options = {
       schema: 'brano'
   }

   const supabaseUrl = 'supabaseUrl'
   const supabaseKey = 'supabaseKey'
   const supabaseClient = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey, options);

   const { data, error } = await supabaseClient
       .from('test_brano')
       .insert([{
           data: 123
   }]);
   ```
4. Got this error:

   ```
   {
       "message":"permission denied for table test_brano",
       "code":"42501",
       "details":null,
       "hint":null
   }
   ```

Links and documentation that we have tried reading (unfortunately we didn't make it work either way):

- https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/7642
- https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/280
- https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/initializing#with-additional-parameters
- https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/1222

Did we missed something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You also need grants, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74193175/1742820

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to the first two steps you did:

1. **Granting usage:**

   ```sql
   CREATE SCHEMA Brano;

   GRANT USAGE 
   ON SCHEMA Brano 
   TO postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, dashboard_user;

   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA brano
   GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO postgres, anon, authenticated, service_role, dashboard_user;
   ```
2. **Exposing the schema in the [Settings](https://app.supabase.com/project/_a/settings/api):**

   [image]

There's a third step that was missing:

3. **Granting actions to be able to insert/select data:**

   ```sql
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
   ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA brano 
   TO postgres, authenticated, service_role, dashboard_user, anon;

   GRANT USAGE, SELECT 
   ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA brano 
   TO postgres, authenticated, service_role, dashboard_user, anon;
   ```

### ⚠️ Warning ⚠️

You must set these grants again for every new table created in the custom schema.

Then you can call it as in your example:

### Supabase JS v2:

```
    const options = {
      db: { schema: 'brano' }
    };
    const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, SUPABASE_KEY, options)
    const d = new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0);
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('test_brano')
      .insert([
        { data: 3, created_at: d }
      ])
    console.log(data)
    if (error) {
        console.log("error getting results");
        throw error;
    }
```

### Supabase JS v1:

```
    const options = {
      schema: 'brano'
    }
    const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, SUPABASE_KEY, options)
    const d = new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0);
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('test_brano')
      .insert([
        { data: 3, created_at: d }
      ])
    console.log(data)
    if (error) {
        console.log("error getting results");
        throw error;
    }
```

Comment: @NikitaChernenko the OP mentioned this in step 2.

Comment: Missed it, I'll delete my comment

Answer (score 3):

To access schema using the newest `Supabase JS SDK'S` you need to use different code [according to the migration documentation](https://%20const%20supabaseUrl%20=%20%27supabaseUrl%27%20const%20supabaseKey%20=%20%27supabaseKey%27):

**New method:**

```
const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_ANON_KEY, {
  db: {
    schema: 'custom',
  },
})
```

The main change is that: *All client specific options within the constructor are keyed to the library: [PR](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/pull/458)*

**And of course you need to run these queries:**

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS  custom;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA custom TO ROLES_YOU_WANT_TO_GIVE_ACCESS;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA custom TO ROLES_YOU_WANT_TO_GIVE_ACCESS;
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, check out this very important github thread: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/10428

There is instructions to local development.

And don't forget to add `-s schema_name` when you diffing your local db changes