# How to access custom schema using `createBrowserSupabaseClient`?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I want to create a supabase client for a schema called 'schooldata' using the `createBrowserSupabaseClient` and can't find any documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access custom schema from supabase-js client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281996/how-to-access-custom-schema-from-supabase-js-client)

Comment: No, I know how to do it using `createClient`, that's why I specifically asked for `createBrowserSupabaseClient`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, first you must create the client inside your file doing the updates:
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/initializing

Then you can use the client `supabase` to access database methods like insert data https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/insert